# Pay Pal webhooks never called

Tags: paypal, webhooks

I have been using Pay Pal for payments from our website for many years without problems.
We currently use Pay Pal buttons to redirect to Pay Pal's website for the payment, and have it return to our website to record the payment.

Now we are trying to configure webhooks in Pay Pal to have it notify our server of payments. The goal is to have auto renewing subscriptions that call the webhook every month when Pay Pal automatically processes the payment.

So I setup the webhooks on,
https://developer.paypal.com/

I setup the webhooks for both the sandbox and live account, and verified it can call the webhook successfully through their webhook simulator.

However, when any payment is made through our website the webhooks are never called?

I've tried everything, but they are never called.

Are the webhooks only called if you make the payment through the Pay Pal API, or are they also called if a payment is made directly, or through a Pay Pal button?

Do they get called for auto-renewing subscriptions?

Comment: So from more testing it seems webhooks are never called for normal Pay Pal payments, or from Pay Pal buttons? If we instead use the Pay Pal API, we can trigger a webhook call, but I'm not sure the point of the API or webhooks?

Comment: Seems like Pay Pal also has IPN, which also calls a webhook on your server (but completely separate from their "webhooks", not sure the point), we do seem to get the IPN events though, so will probably use it instead of the webhooks, which seem like they don't work at all, https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api-basics/notifications/ipn/

Comment: IPN is the old legacy service, which predates webhooks by over a decade

Comment: but IPN works, webhooks don't work at all for most payments, you have to like call the API for it to send you the webhook, what's the point of that, I can just call my own webhook instead of the  API, I need to be notified when anyone pays, however they pay, when ever they pay, where ever they pay, webhooks from my understanding seem to be completely useless

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please understand the distinction as i have quoted from the below sources.

The PayPal REST APIs use webhooks for event notification.[image]

.

---

.

The Paypal BuyButton triggers IPN
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Okay, so now I know that said you did set up the webhooks. However, I am still going to include doing that in my answer anyway.

**Step 1: Creating The PayPal Application**

- Visit URL: https://developer.paypal.com/developer/applications/ and
  click 'create app'

[image]

- Give your Application some name and move forward.

[image]

**Step 2: Adding/Managing WebHooks For Your Application**

- After creating the app, you will be presented with this screen.
  Scroll a bit down and click 'Add Webhook'.

[image]

- Add your desired webhooks (subscription webhooks are here). If you are not sure. Just choose 'All events' (the first option) for the time being. Also, make sure you add a Webhook URL.

[image]

**Step 3: Listening for WebHooks**

- Webhook Details:
  https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api-basics/notifications/webhooks/event-names/#sales
- The webhook you need to listen for auto-renewing subscriptions is: `PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED`

[image]

**Step 4: Verifying you are getting the Callbacks**

- You can visit:
  https://developer.paypal.com/developer/dashboard/webhooks/live to see
  all the webhooks that were fired by PayPal (only stores up to 30 days).
  Personally, I would try to log *everything* that I receive at my
  endpoint and compare my log with PayPal's log.

[image]

**Step 4: Validating the Callbacks**

- Furthermore, you can also visit:
  https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api-basics/notifications/webhooks/rest/#to-use-the-paypal-rest-sdks-to-verify-event-notifications
  to get the sample code(s) to validate the callback (webhooks) once you receive
  them.

[image]

Comment: So from more testing it seems webhooks are never called for normal Pay Pal payments, or from Pay Pal buttons? If we instead use the Pay Pal API, we can trigger a webhook call, but I'm not sure the point of the API or webhooks?

Comment: vs IPN, which actually seems to work unlike webhooks, which seem useless

Comment: @James https://stackoverflow.com/a/56309653/9920079 and, yes calling the API is the only way for the webhook to work.

Comment: @James If I may suggest, please just use https://stripe.com/docs It's *extremely* straightforward, quick, and easy to setup. As a web developer, I hate PayPal the most among all payment processors. PayPal's APIs are bad and disorganized. And worse, their tech support rarely replies.

Comment: @James Sandbox webhooks don't work for me either - they used to, about 10 days ago, but they don't anymore and it's blocking me from delivering too.  PayPal is an atrocious company to deal with as a developer.  They can't even get a nuget package out of beta.  Stripe is vastly better.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to add a webhook from the developer site but I couldn't. so I ran this API: https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/notifications/webhooks.
and it has been created.
body of API :

```
{
    "url": "{{webhook_url}}",
    "event_types": [
        {
            "name": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```